# Where should I update my state based on my passed in props?

Tags: reactjs

```
const myComponent({prop1, prop2,...}) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState(....);

    

}
```

If I want to immediately update my local state based on the props, where should I do this?
Is there a special event or I can do it right after the `useState` line in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the variable prop as a dependency to [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const myComponent({prop1, prop2,...}) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState(....);
    useEffect(() => {
       // some logic to update local state
       setState(...)
    },[prop1])
    

}
```

Comment: if this was the old style component, this would be done in the componentdidmount event?

Comment: @Blankman, for class components you can achieve it using componentDidUpdate lifecycle hook - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce